# Poor performance on css class typing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Im facing problem with poor performance of css prompting mechanism.

Can I dissable this function as I usually know what css class I would like to add ?

Problem may be seen on the vide: http://screencast.com/t/6dHBMXOf82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from ReSharper 6.1 (pre-release builds for this version are [already available for download](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Early+Access+Program), you can turn on/off IntelliSense for each language under ReSharper > Options > Environment > IntelliSense.

In addition, the 6.1 release introduces a set of performance improvements that could make your problem simply go away.